# How does Lisp's getf work for a list?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

So I have a simple piece of code:

```
(defun lol (z) (getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :z))
```

And when I start the function:

```
(lol '(a))
```

It just gives me NIL instead of 1. Isn't the above technically the same as:

```
(getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :a)
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few other answers that cover the issue, but I think that sometimes an example is useful.  The important part is that symbols have *packages* and (a few caveats aside) a symbol with a given name in one package isn't the same symbol as a symbol with the same name in another package.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *plist* (list 'a 1 ':a 2))
*PLIST*
CL-USER> (first *plist*)
A
CL-USER> (third *plist*)
:A
CL-USER> (eql (first *plist*) (third *plist*))
NIL
CL-USER> (getf *plist* 'a)
1
CL-USER> (getf *plist* ':a)
2
```

Now, what might make this a bit confusing at the beginning is that the way symbols are *printed* doesn't always show the full package name of the symbol.  The "CL-USER" in the prompt above indicates that the current package is the CL-USER package, so symbols in that package, or symbols *used* by that package aren't shown with their package name.  If we create a new package and switch to it, and print ***plist***, we can see this:

```
CL-USER> (defpackage #:temp)
#<PACKAGE "TEMP">
CL-USER> (in-package #:temp)
#<COMMON-LISP:PACKAGE "TEMP">
TEMP> cl-user::*plist*
(COMMON-LISP-USER::A 1 :A 2)
```

Note that the first element of ***plist*** is printed with a "COMMON-LISP-USER" ("CL-USER" is a nickname for "COMMON-LISP-USER").  Now, the symbol **:A** was printed the same way.  What's the story with that?  Common Lisp has a special package, called "KEYWORD", and symbols in that package are called keyword symbols.  They're pretty much like other symbols, except that they're all bound to themselves (so evaluating **:a**produces **:a**, and quoting isn't necessary), they're all external, and are typically printed with a single colon as their prefix.  You *can* write the keyword prefix, though, if you want:

```
TEMP> 'keyword::a
:A
TEMP> 'keyword:b
:B
TEMP> keyword::c  ; no need to quote
:C
TEMP> keyword:d
:D
```

So, if you want to write a function that takes a property list indicator and retrieves the value in some fixed property list for it, you'd do something like this (note that the indicators in a property list don't have to be symbols, as the last example shows):

```
(defun example (indicator)
  (getf '(:a 1 :b 2 c 3 4 5) indicator))
```

```
CL-USER> (example :a)        ; OR ':a OR keyword::A OR ...
1
CL-USER> (example keyword:b) ; OR ...
2
CL-USER> (example 'c)        ; OR 'cl-user::c OR ...
3
CL-USER> (example 4)         ; OR (+ 2 2) OR ...
5
```

Answer (score 2):

`(getf L :z)` finds the value associated to the symbol `:z` in the list currently bound to `L`:

- `:z` has almost no relation with the symbol `z`
- `:z` has no relation with the value currently bound to `z`

At least, read [Programming in the Large: Packages and Symbols](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html) (and, why not, the whole book).

You cannot bind `z` to `a` and expect `:z` to evaluate to `:a`. What you could do is to bind `z` to `a` and access the symbol `:a` based on the current value of `z`. Also,  symbol `:z` is a keyword, which cannot be used as a local variable.

```
(defun lol (z) (getf '(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3) z))
```

In the above, the local variable `z` will hold a value, which will be passed to the call to `getf`.

In this call:

```
(lol '(a))
```

... the local variable `z` is bound to `(a)`, a constant list whose first element is the symbol `a`. This value, when used in `lol`, has no chance of returning anything else than `nil` because [`GETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) searches for the same, identical element in the list (the same memory address, if you want).

[`GETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) is supposed to be called with a symbol, because two occurences of `package:symbol` refers to the same data-structure (like a hash-map). You have to call it like so:

```
(lol 'symbol)
```

or, since keywords evaluate to themselves:

```
(lol :symbol)
```

In your case, `(lol :a)` will get you 1.

Answer (score 1):

First getf works on a [property list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#property_list) which is a particular kind of list. Also the function lol does not use the variable z. It always looks up the `:z` **keyword** in the property list. If you want to parametrize the symbol looked up by lol you wouldn't pass a list (`'(a)`) but a keyword.

```
(defun lol (z)
  (getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) z))

(lol :a) ; => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `(a)` is a list containing at its head the symbol with the name `a`, interned in the current package and `:z` is the symbol with the name `z` interned in the `keyword` package. The value bound to `:z` is co-incidentally, "the symbol named z, interned in the keyword package".

It is never the case that the value bound to the symbol `z` (in the current package) influences the value of `:z`.

So, no, `(defun lol (z) (getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :z))` defines a function that returns the same value as `(getf (list :a 1 :b 2 :c 3) :z)`. To fix it, replace `:z` with `z` and call the function like `(lol :a)`, since lists and symbols are essentially not interchangeable.